# delete files extracted from tar archive

Tags: shell, tar, rm

Occasionally I extract a tar archive into entirely the wrong directory. Usually because some archives have all files one directory down and some don't.

```
tar -xvf archive.tar
```

What's the best way to undo/reverse this?

List the files contained in archive.tar and pipe them to rm ...?

Extra internet points for handling files that may have been overwritten by the extract.

Comment: `Extra internet points for handling files that may have been overwritten by the extract.` -- There is **no way** to determine that after the archive has been extracted.

Answer (score 1):

My google-fu was weak.

From the comments on this [http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2573/remove-all-files-previously-extracted-from-a-tar.gz-file.](commandlinefu entry)

```
tar tf <file.tar.gz> | sort -r | while read file; do if [ -d "$file" ]; then rmdir "$file"; else rm -f "$file"; fi; done
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.

*If someone knows a way to handle overwritten files I will mark that as the correct answer.*

Comment: How to handle overwritten files: restore from backup. There's no other record of what the directory used to look like, unless the directory happens to be under source control (and the `tar` file didn't somehow overwrite the repo metadata).